# read a file with single quote data and store it in a list in python

Tags: python, list

When I was trying to read a file and store it in a list its failing to store string which is inside a single quote as single value in list.

sample file:

```
12 3 'dsf dsf'
```

the list should contain

```
listname = [12, 3, 'dsf dsf']
```

I am able to do this like below:

```
listname = [12, 3, 'dsf', 'dsf']
```

Please help

Comment: `listname = [12, 3, dsf dsf]` is not a valid list. Do you mean `listname = [12, 3, 'dsf dsf']`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('input.txt') as inp:
...     print(list(csv.reader(inp, delimiter=' ', quotechar="'"))[0])
... 
['12', '3', 'dsf dsf']
```

input.txt is the file containing your data in the example.

Comment: Can I have multiple quetechar?

Comment: @ARK I don't think so, the docs say it must be a one character string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shlex` module to split your data in a simple way.

```
import shlex
data = open("sample file", 'r')
print shlex.split(data.read())
```

Try it:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r"(?<=')[\w\s]+(?=')|\w+")
with open ("filename.txt") as my_file:
    my_list = my_regex.findall(my_file.read())
    print(my_list)
```

Output for file content `12 3 'dsf dsf'`:

```
['12', '3', 'dsf dsf']
```

---

**RegEx explanation:**

```
(?<=')     # matches if there's a single quote *before* the matched pattern
[\w\s]+    # matches one or more alphanumeric characters and spaces
(?=')      # matches if there's a single quote *after* the matched pattern
|          # match either the pattern above or below
\w+        # matches one or more alphanumeric characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
>>> l = ['12', '3', 'dsf', 'dsf']
>>> l[2:] = [' '.join(l[2:])]
>>> l
['12', '3', 'dsf dsf']
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to parse the data. Which is:

- split it into tokens
- interpret the resulting sequence

  - in your case, each token can be interpreted separately

For the 1st task:

- each token is:

  - a set nonspace characters, or
  - a quote, then anything until another quote.
- the separator is a single space (you didn't specify if runs of spaces/other whitespace characters are valid)

Interpretation:

- quoted: take the enclosed text, discarding the quotes
- non-quoted: convert to integer if possible (you didn't specify if it always is/should be an interger)
- (you also didn't specify if it's always 2 integers + quoted string - i.e. if this combination should be enforced)

Since the syntax is very simple, the two tasks can be done at the same time:

```
import re
i=0
maxi=len(line)
tokens=[]
re_sep=r"\s"
re_term=r"\S+"
re_quoted=r"'(?P<enclosed>[^']*)'"
re_chunk=re.compile("(?:(?P<term>%(re_term)s)"\
                     "|(?P<quoted>%(re_quoted)s))"\
                    "(?:%(re_sep)s|$)"%locals())
del re_sep,re_term,re_quoted
while i<maxi:
    m=re.match(re_chunk,line,i)
    if not m: raise ValueError("invalid syntax at char %d"%i)
    gg=m.groupdict()
    token=gg['term']
    if token:
        try: token=int(token)
        except ValueError: pass
    elif gg['quoted']:
        token=gg['enclosed']
    else: assert False,"invalid match. locals=%r"%locals()
    tokens.append(token)
    i+=m.end()
    del m,gg,token
```

---

This is an example of how it can be done by hand. You can, however, reuse any existing parsing algorithm that can process the same syntax. `csv` and `shlex` suggested in other answers are examples. Do note though that they likely accept *other* syntax, too, which you may or may not want. E.g.:

- `shlex` also accepts double quotes and constructs like `"asd"fgh` and `'asd'\''fgh'`
- `csv` allows multiple consecutive separators (producing an empty element) and things like `'asd'fgh` (stripping the quotes) and `asd'def'` (leaving the quotes intact)